# Changing DetailViewController on button click in RootViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

How can we load the `DetailViewController` with other `UIViewController` by button a click in the `RootViewController`?

I was trying this all day long but unable to get the solution. Tired of googling the same stuff again and again. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where is your details view controller defined.

If in a separate nid:
   Load it with [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"" owner:self options:nil];

Else code create it (or get it with an IBOutlet)

Then display it using modalViewController (- presentModalViewController:animated:)

Hope it helps.